# Changing the color of a paragraph in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

So I have a button within a paragraph. When the user pushes the button, I want it to change the background color of the specific paragraph it is in. here is the JQuery that I have so far:

```
$('<button/>',
    {
        text: "Done",
        click: function () {
            $("p:first").addClass("first");
            $(".first").css({ 'background-color': 'green' });
        }
    });
```

My idea is to place the paragraph into a specific class first, then give it a background color. However my button is not working and when I check the console, I do not get any errors. Anything else I can try?

Comment: its better. if you post your html too..

Comment: How are you targetting the button?  Give your button an id, and then reference that button.

Comment: The `button` element created does not appear to have `p` element child ?

Comment: You've just created a button, not selected one

Comment: Is requirement to create a `button` element having child `p` element ? Or, `p` element having child `button` element ? `js` at Question appear to create dynamic `button` element that does not contain a `p` element ? Where `click` event is attached to `button` object created by `jQuery("<button />")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current `button` jQuery object at Question does not have `p` child element.

Try substituting `html:` for `text:` ; wrapping `"Done"` string within `<p></p>` ; using `context` at selector within `click` event to reference `this` `button` element ; using `.appendTo()` to append jQuery object `button` to document

```js
$("<button/>", {
  html: "<p>Done</p>",
  click: function() {
    $("p:first", this).addClass("first");
  }
}).appendTo("body")
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following. Use `closest` function to find parent `p` and `css` function to change background color.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
     $(this).closest('p').css('background-color', 'red');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <button>Click</button>
</p>
```

Comment: `p` appear intended to be child element of `button` element ?

Comment: OP said he has a button within a paragraph. @guest271314

Comment: _"OP said he has a button within a paragraph"_ Yes, `html` at solution has `p` parent element with `button` child ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.myclass
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.newclass
{
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="myclass">This is a paragraph.
<button id="changecolor"> change color </button>
</p>
<script>
$('#changecolor').click(function()
{
$(this).parent().removeClass('myclass').addClass('newclass');
}

);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user pushes the button, I want it to change the background color of the specific paragraph it is in.

The codes below do the work!

```js
$('p button').click(function(){
  $(this).parent('p').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  <button>Click Me</button>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</p>

<p>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  <button>Click Me</button>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</p>

<p>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  <button>Click Me</button>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</p>
```